# How to allocate 500MB+ physically contiguous memory in a Linux kernel module and copy data to that memory from a userspace process?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, device-driver, ioctl, kmalloc

I tried using `kmalloc()` but it's not providing more than 4MB. Also, can I use ioctl to transfer that large data from a user process to a kernel module? Is there any limitations for the buffer size?

I also read some documentation about `__get_free_page()` and `dma_alloc_coherent()` but these functions also do not provide that much memory.

Comment: Any particular reason why you would need such a large chunk of physically contiguous memory? It kind of sounds like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I need to store temporarily a large binary file that contains many commands. I need to pass the real physical address of the commands to a particular hardware.

Comment: Have a look at the CMA feature in kernel.

Comment: You can reserve hugepages at boot.